# ListView item delete when switching to other activity android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I require to dynamically add item to listView from FirstActivity using a button, and the listView is located at SecondActivity.My problem is that I only can add one item but not multiple, once I press the button, it switch to SecondActivity, and only the first item will be added at the first row. When I switch back to FirstActivity and press again, it cannot added item to second row, it will replace the first row again. The objective I want to achieve is when Button at FirstActivity being press, it will add one item to listView at second activity. When the button being press second time, it will added second item to listView at secondActivity, third time --- and so on.

**The code at my first activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
PressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
PressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
hours = 3;
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Hours", hours);
    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

**The code at my SecondActivity
    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ListView practiceList;
    Button btnBack;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_previous_practices);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int hours = extras.getInt("Hours");


    if (practiceList == null) {
        practiceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.practiceList);
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    listItems.add(Integer.toString(hours));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: You need to pass to second Activity not `Item`, but the whole `List<Item>`

Comment: What means? I am try to pass the value of "hour" from first activity button to second activity listView, and it work. But the objective I want is when user press it, it add one item at list view, user press twice, it add second item at list view, user only can add by using button at first activity. The problem I face is the listview item will delete when i switch from second activity to firstactivity and press the button again, it not added at second row but just replace the first row

Comment: Please see answer

Answer (score 0):

in FirstActivity:

```
final List<Integer> hours = new ArrayList<Integer>()

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PressButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    PressButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hours.add(3);
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Hours", hours);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

in the SecondActivity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
List<Integer> hours = extras.getIntegerArrayList("Hours");
```

Now it will be list that you can use in SecondActivity. Problem that when you click backButton in SecondActivity it destroyed and on each time when you click on Button in FirstActivity App creates new SecondActivity. So obvious that it "forgets" previous values.